# Why does java assertion have no effect?

Tags: java, assertion

i have this code:

```
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        assert (9 < 6):"wrong"; 
        System.out.println("ok"); 
    }
}
```

I compile with "javac C.java".
I execute with "java C".

It prints "ok". Why does it not work?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as assertions are usually used for debugging they need to be enabled explicitly. hence, add **`-ea`** or **`-enableassertions`** parameter when starting your program `java -ea C`

Comment: Thank you. With this option it throws an error.